# What does [1] mean in the output of any command executed on R command line?

Tags: r

I think the question is self-explanatory.

Whenever we execute any command in R, the output is preceded by [1]. What does that [1] represent?

Comment: Try `print(1:100)` :)

Comment: I feel stupid!!!!! But funnily none talks about this.......I spent quite some time trying to look for this........ :)

Comment: Just to get it right .....................It means that [1] represents the first value returned by the function called?

Comment: yes it is indicating that only try list(s=c(1:2),b=c(2:5)) you will get two [1] since two vectors are being printed

Comment: It's the first value _printed_.

Comment: There are places where I have seen [[1]]. How is it different from [1]?

Comment: @Shaun [[1]] means first element of a list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this question was only implicitly answered in the comments, but the answer would appear to be that the `[1]` and every similar number at the beginning of a line indicates that the adjacent element is the nth element printed.

It's not clear to me why this is needed for something as simple as:

```
a <- "alpha"
a
```

which outputs

```
[1] "alpha"
```

Nonetheless, it appears to be a consistent prefix on any line of data presented on the console.

Answer (score -1):

It defines a line number. Try and run a program where you expect two or three lines of output.

Comment: Hello, please read [Why is it considered inappropriate and unprofessional to type in all capital letters?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-considered-inappropriate-and-unprofessional-to-type-in-all-capital-letters). Thank you.