# Data from hive to R to bash

Tags: r, bash, hive

Im trying to execute hive query in `R` using `system` command. This R function is called from a `Bash` script.

R Code

```
hivedata<-function(query)
{
  data <- system(paste0("hive -S -e ", query), wait = TRUE,intern=TRUE)
  if (identical(data, character(0))){data=NULL}
  message("return value:")
  message(data)
  message("return value type:")
  message(class(data))

  return(cat(data))
}   
if (length(query)>0 && is.na(query)==FALSE){
  data=hivedata(query)
  print(data)
}
```

Bash function

```
gethivedata(){
  set -f #disable aterisk in sql getting expanded as filenames
  query=$1
    data=`Rscript hivedata.r "'$query'"`
    echo $data
}
```

Calling function in Bash

```
totalcount=$(gethivedata " select count(*) from hivedb.hivetable ")
```

The outputs

```
[usr@host dir]$ totalcount=$(execute_sql " select count(*) from 
hivedb.hivetable ")
return value:
0
return value type:
character
-------------------------------
[usr@host dir]$ echo $totalcount
0NULL
```

When `cat` is not used, the output value comes as `[1]"0"`. Because R returns the index also with the output. When `cat` is used then the output becomes `0NULL`. I want only the actual value which is "0"

[What does [1] mean in the output of any command executed on R command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595066/what-does-1-mean-in-the-output-of-any-command-executed-on-r-command-line)

Comment: Did you consider using RODBC and the Hive driver provided by your distro, instead of this bizarre workaround...?

Comment: Yes. As those doesnt work becuase of some config issue. im using this workaround

Comment: Then you would probably be better off spooling `hive` output into a CSV file. Even better, use `beeline` (w/ the appropriate JDBC URL) which has options such as  `--outputformat=tsv2 --showHeader=false`